# How to convert Azure ACS to Azure AD Authentication in existing ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application that uses Azure ACS authentication with a ClientId and ClientSecret. Now as ACS is deprecated, I have to migrate it to Azure AD authentication which has ClientId and TenantId.

What changes will be there in the authentication function? And can I use my previous CSOM code as it is? Data is on SharePoint.